# How do I Refresh iScroll when images load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll

I am using iScroll in a web app built on jQuery Mobile, and using iScroll for scrolling.  One feature loads an rss feed item into a page, and then changes to that page. iScroll works quite well, except for one thing:

iScroll uses the height of the page when it initiates, however, this is before any images in the content are loaded.  Once the images load, the height of the page changes, and then I get the 'bounce-back' effect from iScroll.

How do I determine when the images are loaded? or alternatively, has anyone else experienced this problem and maybe used a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) will allow you to detect when your images have loaded.